# Understanding a proof

Tags: real-analysis

> $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces, and $T$ is a linear map from $X$ to $Y$ that is continuous at $0$, show $T$ is bounded.

> If $T$ is continuous at $0\in X$, there is a neighborhood $U$  of $0$ such that $T(U)\subset\{y\in Y:\|y\|\leq1\}$, and $U$  must contain a ball $B=\{x\in X:\|x\|\leq\delta\}$ about $0$; thus $\|Tx\|\leq1$ when $\|x\|\leq\delta$. Since $T$ commutes with scalar multiplication, it follows that $\|Tx\|\leq a\delta^{-1}$ whenever $\|x\|\leq a$, that is, $\|Tx\|\leq\delta^{-1}\|x\|$.

And this shows $T$ is bounded.

The proof is from Folland analysis book, and I think there are questions related to this on the exchange, but my confusion is on a more elementary part. I basically dont understand how  it went from T is bounded for all $\|x\|<a$ to any arbitrary $x\in X$.
Here is what I did trying to reproduce the proof with details

Consider $W=\{y\in Y: \|y\|\leq 1\}$, then by definition of $T$ being cts at $0$, there must exist some neighborhood $U$ about $0$ and $T(U) \subset W$. Fix this $\delta >0$, now consider a ball and $x\in B_\delta(0) \subset U$ , then $\|Tx\|\leq 1$. Let $a>1$, we have $\|T\frac{\delta}{a}x\|\leq1 \implies \|Tx\|\leq \frac{a}{\delta}$ and since $x\in B_\delta(0)\implies \|\frac{\delta}{a}x\|\leq \delta\implies \|x\|\leq a$. Now, pick $C=\frac{1}{\delta}$ , and consider any arbitary $x\in X$, then there exists $a>0$ such that $\|x\|=0$ and we have $\|Tx\|\leq Ca=C\|x\|$, hence it holds for all $x$?

Probably some trivial things I have missed?

Comment: When one says that a linear operator $T$ is bounded, one means that $T$ is bounded on bounded sets.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks I didnt know that

Comment: Specifically,  you usually look for the bounds on unit vectors, and the sup of that becomes the norm of the operator.   By linearity,  any vector can be scaled to a unit vector, and the open neighborhood around each scale the same way

Comment: One uses the term bounded because it is bounded in the operator norm
$$
\|T\| = \sup_{x\in X} \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}
$$